# Replicating a CSS3 animation in IE9

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I understand CSS3 animations won't work in IE9 down, but I have made up a transition for a header which becomes fixed and shrinks for modern browsers using the following CSS.

```
/** This fires when viewport scrolls down past 60px **/
.fm-container.small .branding {width:120px;transition: all 0.2s ease;}
.fm-container.small ul.prim-nav {margin-top:8px;transition: all 0.2s ease;}
.fm-container.small .prim-nav li ul a {font-size:100%;}
.fm-container.small .navicon:after {top:15px;transition: all 0.2s ease;}
.fm-container.small .highlight {opacity:0;}

/** This fires when viewport is at 0px from top **/  
.fm-container.large .branding {width:200px;transition: all 0.2s ease;}
.fm-container.large ul.prim-nav {margin-top:30px;transition: all 0.2s ease;}
.fm-container.large .prim-nav li ul a {font-size:100%;}
```

And the jQuery:

```
// Header scroll function
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Add class for animate size changes when scrolled
    if($(document).scrollTop()>60){
        $(".fm-container").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
    } else{
        $(".fm-container").removeClass("small").addClass("large");  
    }
});
```

So my question is, knowing this won't work in IE9, is there anyone able to help me turn this in into a jQuery animated for all browsers, modern and old?

I've made a few attempts but it always seems to animate in weird ways.

I have tried making it up like:

```
// Header scroll function
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Add class for animate size changes when scrolled
    if($(document).scrollTop()>60){
        $(".fm-container").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
        $(".fm-container.small").animate(width:"120px");
        $(".fm-container.small ul.prim-nav").animate(marginTop:"8px");
        $(".fm-container.small .navicon:after").animate(top:"15px");
        $(".fm-container.small .highlight").animate(opacity:"0");
    } else{
        $(".fm-container").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
        $(".fm-container.small").animate(width:"200px");
        $(".fm-container.small ul.prim-nav").animate(marginTop:"30px");
        $(".fm-container.small .navicon:after").animate(top:"12px");
        $(".fm-container.small .highlight").animate(opacity:"1");   
    }
});
```

But for one this never seems to spring back when I scroll to the top and two, it seems like I am doing this in a really basic way (as my skills are basic) but I am trying to learn how to do this properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should add that I am using Modernizer already however I can't seem to understand how to make the CSS3 fallback option work. Seems to always default to attempting CSS3 transitions and ignoring the modernizer fallback. In short, if assistance with Modernizer is easier/better, I'm happy to work with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted... I came across the following (I made my edits as needed). Posting this here in case anyone comes across it for future reference.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 33)
        {
            if($('.fm-container').data('size') == 'big')
            {
                $('.fm-container').data('size','small');
                $('.fm-container').stop().animate({height:'60px'},200);
                $('.branding').stop().animate({width:'120px'},200);
                $('.logo-spacer').stop().animate({width:'120px'},200);
                $('.fm-container ul.prim-nav').stop().animate({marginTop:'8px'},200);
                $('.fm-container .highlight').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},200);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($('.fm-container').data('size') == 'small')
            {
                $('.fm-container').data('size','big');
                $('.fm-container').stop().animate({height:'85px'},200);
                $('.branding').stop().animate({width:'200px'},200);
                $('.logo-spacer').stop().animate({width:'200px'},200);
                $('.fm-container ul.prim-nav').stop().animate({marginTop:'30px'},200);
                $('.fm-container .highlight').stop().animate({opacity:'1'},200);
            }  
        }
});
```